# Android app crashes when viewing user profiles

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

To replicate this,  I click on the upper left corner, then select my own user profile.  As it animates the closing of that menu bar,  the app crashes with a RuntimeException in the Obligation file.

I also tried to load another user's profile from a separate question, which also resulted in a crash.

---

- Stack Exchange: *1.0.22*
- Android: *4.4*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you update the app? In version 1.0.23, it fixes some problems where the app might crash when loading user profiles.

Comment: Dangit, that fixed it. It had automatically updated last night, so I didn't know there'd be _another_ version available.

Answer (score 3):

Version 1.0.22 has a bug with viewing user profiles.  Please update to 1.0.23 ASAP.